# Listener afteritemexpand from ExtJS 4.2.1

Tags: extjs, tree, listener, expand

I am working with a treepanel in ExtJS 4.2.1.
I used to set modifications on dom elements (precisely change the class name) with the listener `afteritemexpand` when I expand nodes of my tree. In fact it was to have leaves with even index with a different color than leaves with odd color.
It worked fine.
Getting the ids of the items which interest me, I can access them, and then modify the className.
I did the same way for another tree but the problem is that when I create this tree I expand it with an `expandAll()`, so the listener `afteritemexpand` is not called.
I need this `expandAll()`, but I need the `afteritemexpand` listener too. The reason I use this listener is because I have an easy access to item.id with the prototype  `afteritemexpand( node, index, item, eOpts )`. With this id I can get the element I am looking for with the `Ext.get(id)` method.
I can do it with the `afterlayout` listener but I would rather not because the access to the id is not so easy.
I can't do it with the `load` listener because the dom elements are not present yet.

So I want to know, how could I totally expand my tree and use the code I made for my `afteritemexpand`?

Here is my listener so you can understand better want I want to do (in fact just add `'tree-even-node'` to the className of even leaves of my tree).

```
listeners: {
                afteritemexpand: function( node, index, item, eOpts ){
                    var domLeaf = Ext.get(item.id).next();

                    for ( var int = 0; int < node.childNodes.length; int++) {
                        if (node.childNodes[int].data.leaf && (int % 2) == 0) {
                                if (ids.indexOf(domLeaf.id) == -1) {
                                    ids[indiceIds] = domLeaf.id;
                                    indiceIds++;
                                }
                        }
                        domLeaf = domLeaf.next();
                    }
                    for ( var int = 0; int < ids.length; int++) {
                        domLeaf = Ext.get(ids[int]);
                        if (domLeaf != null) {
                            for ( var int2 = 0; int2 < domLeaf.dom.children.length; int2++) {
                                if (domLeaf.dom.children[int2].className.search('tree-even-node') == -1){
                                    domLeaf.dom.children[int2].className += ' tree-even-node';
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally used both `load` and `afteritemexpand` listeners. The loading enables me getting the right ids quite easily and I can set the classNames with `afteritemexpand` because I know the dom elements are loaded, so I don't get a `null` with my `Ext.get(id)`.
It works great.

Here is the code:

```
listeners: {
                load: function(node, records, successful, eOpts) {
                    var ownertree = records.store.ownerTree;
                    var boundView = ownertree.dockedItems.items[1].view.id;
                    var generalId = boundView+'-record-';

                    if (!node.tree.root.data.leaf) {
                        // Process each child node
                        node.tree.root.cascadeBy(function(currentChild) {
                            // Process only leaf
                            if (currentChild.data.leaf) {
                                var nodeId = ""+generalId+currentChild.internalId;
                                var index = currentChild.data.index;
                                if ( (index % 2) == 0 && ids.indexOf(nodeId) == -1 ) {
                                    // even nodes
                                    ids[indiceIds] = nodeId;
                                    indiceIds++;
                                } 
                               console.log(ids);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                },
                afteritemexpand: function( node, index, item, eOpts ){
                    for ( var int = 0; int < ids.length; int++) {
                        domLeaf = Ext.get(ids[int]);
                        if (domLeaf != null) {
                            for ( var int2 = 0; int2 < domLeaf.dom.children.length; int2++) {
                                if (domLeaf.dom.children[int2].className.search('tree-even-node') == -1){
                                    domLeaf.dom.children[int2].className += ' tree-even-node';
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
```